# arc4random_uniform float value

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My question is pretty basic: how can I make `arc4random_uniform` return a random value between 1.75 and 2.25?

This code below is only returning me `Int` values.

```
import SpriteKit

let duration = CGFloat((arc4random_uniform(50)+175)/100) //random between 1.75 and 2.25 attempt

print("Duration:", duration)
```

If you want, you can download the playground file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb62zjjxjz42vtf/MyPlayground.playground.zip?dl=0).

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: Code not tested: `let duration: CGFloat = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(51)) + 175.0) / 100.0`.

Comment: It worked pretty well!! Thank you!!

Comment: By the way, why did you randomize 51, instead of 50?

Comment: Because `arc4random_uniform(N)` returns a number between `0` and `N-1`. So to get a number between `0` and `50` you need `arc4random_uniform(51)`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about the `N-1`!! Thank you again!!